# NSManagedObjectContext crash while deleting DB file

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

my App is crashing like hell,when i try to remove the local storage(removing db file) while some Db operation is running background.
Is there any method to stop the db operations?
or any other possible solution for this problem?

Comment: could you please post some code how you are removing the local storage?

Comment: Of course you have to tear down your whole core data stack before you can safely delete the file. Related: [How to force coredata to rebuild sqlite database model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357010/how-to-force-coredata-to-rebuild-sqlite-database-model)